# How to delete elements in a column according to values in another column

Tags: r, filter

I have a DF with three columns, one with farms, another with animal ID and the third one with days.

EXAMPLE

```
Farm  ID  DAYS
A     1   -3
A     1   -2
A     1   -1
A     1    0
B     2   -18
B     2   -17
B     2    1
B     2    2
C     3   -10
C     3   -8
C     3    0
C     3    2
D     4   -20
D     4    2
D     4    7
D     4    8
```

Each cow has many animals and each animal has days between -60 to 30 relative to day 0. But not all the animals have all days in the sequence. I want to remove those animals that have not day 0 (zero).

OBS: Farms can have the same number of animals. Then animal X can be present in different farms

Desired output:

```
Farm  ID  DAYS
A     1   -3
A     1   -2
A     1   -1
A     1    0
C     3   -10
C     3   -8
C     3    0
C     3    2
```

Any help please? Sorry if I am not very clear in my explanation.

Comment: It would help if you showed your desired output based on this.

Answer (score 2):

Or with base R, your data.frame being called `mydf`:

```
d6030[d6030$Farm %in% d6030$Farm[d6030$DAYS==0], ]
#   Farm ID DAYS
#1     A  1   -3
#2     A  1   -2
#3     A  1   -1
#4     A  1    0
#9     C  3  -10
#10    C  3   -8
#11    C  3    0
#12    C  3    2
```

***NB:*** *Alternatively, you can do `d6030[with(d6030, Farm %in% Farm[DAYS==0]), ]` to get the same output*

Comment: are you sure you mean 'ddd'?

Comment: Sorry but I dont get it, will be this my command? mydf[mydf$Farm %in% mydf$Farm[mydf$days==0], ]

Comment: @AgustinSilva yes but with `days` in upper cases if `mydf` is what you have posted

Comment: My df is called d6030, then I tried 
d6030[with(d6030, d6030$`finaldata$Farm` %in% d6030$`Finaldata$Farm`[DIFF_IN_DAYS==0]), ]. But I do not get what I want. I can see just the variables names.

Comment: @AgustinSilva what is `finaldata` ? Please post the head of your data.frame exactly as it is

Comment: It is too long. It does not allow me to do it. `finaldata$Farm` is the variable farm. Because this df was created from another df called finaldata.

Comment: @AgustinSilva `finaldata$Farm` is the variable `Farm` only if the name of the df is `finaldata`. Please give me some hints on your data structure, it will help me give you an answer that works with your data

Comment: DF=d6030
variables= finaldata$Farm    finaldata$Cow   diff_in_days

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`. first we `group_by` ID, then we `filter` out `any` that do not have a 0:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(ID) %>%
        filter(any(DAYS==0))
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: ID [2]

    Farm    ID  DAYS
  (fctr) (int) (int)
1      A     1    -3
2      A     1    -2
3      A     1    -1
4      A     1     0
5      C     3   -10
6      C     3    -8
7      C     3     0
8      C     3     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but I got this message. Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: that's weird - is your data called `dat`?

Comment: It is not. It is called d6030. d6030 %>% group_by(d6030$ID) %>%
        filter(any(DIFF_IN_DAYS==0)). obs=diff_in_days is class 'difftime' atomic.

Comment: d6030 %>% group_by(d6030$`finaldata$Cow`) %>% filter(any(DIFF_IN_DAYS==0)). Error: unexpected symbol in "d6030 %>% group_by(d6030$`finaldata$Cow`) %>% filter(any(DIFF_IN_DAYS==0))."

Comment: d6030 %>% group_by(d6030$`finaldata$Cow`) %>%
  filter(any(d6030$DIFF_IN_DAYS==0))
> filter(any(d6030$DIFF_IN_DAYS==0))
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: don;t use the $ in the `group_by` : `d6030 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(any(DIFF_IN_DAYS==0))`

Comment: d6030 %>% group_by(`finaldata$Cow`) %>% filter(any(DIFF_IN_DAYS==0)) 

I have to use $ because `finaldata$Cow` is the name of my variable.

This is what I get: d6030 %>% group_by(`finaldata$Cow`) %>% filter(any(DIFF_IN_DAYS==0))
Error: object 'DIFF_IN_DAYS' not found

Comment: d6030 %>% group_by(`finaldata$Cow`) %>% filter(any(diff_in_days==0)) . It seems to be it worked. But when I check seeing animals just with days 0 I do not get the same number.

Comment: you seem to be confused about what data is where. You should paste the output of `dput(head(finaldata))` and `dput(head(d6030))` into your original question.